# Ruby Unidentified Method for nil No Method Error

Tags: ruby, null, each

I'm attempting to run this code:

```
def get_linedict(filename,source)
`dwarfdump -l #{source} > dwarfline.txt`
linefile = File.new("dwarfline.txt","r")

match = false

linefile.readlines.each do |line|
    puts line
    if /uri:/ =~ line
        file = line.match(/.*\/(.*)"/)[1]
        if file == filename
            match = true
        end
        puts file
        puts match
    end
end
```

And when I do I get the following error:

```
assn4.rb:12:in `block in get_linedict': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from assn4.rb:9:in `each'
from assn4.rb:9:in `get_linedict'
from assn4.rb:126:in `block in <main>'
from assn4.rb:80:in `each'
from assn4.rb:80:in `<main>'
```

If I change my each loop to only print the lines it's reading, it works fine.  As I understand it, the error I'm getting comes from something being nil which shouldn't be, but if that error is coming from the each loop, why am I able to print out the file?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you first have to ask if line.match gets something, before calling an element of the desired array.

```
line.match(/.*\/(.*)"/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `line.match(/.*\/(.*)"/)` the result is `nil`. Then you attempt to access `nil` as an `Array`. That is when you get `undefined method []' for nil:NilClass`.

And as for this part of your question

> but if that error is coming from the each loop, why am I able to print out the file?

The each loop is causing your code to fail and halt when the error occurs. Since you are attempting to print `file` **after** the errors, you are actually not printing out `file` on that iteration of the loop.

Be aware that `line` might not be `nil`. Your regular expression is probably just not covering all the cases you think it is, so one of the `match` calls is failing and returning `nil`.